# Implementing HW Alpha Test in HLSL

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl

I'm currently trying to implement the HW Alpha Test from SM2 in HLSL.

I know there are fairly straight forward methods of achieving this, i.e. 
clip(alphaVal <= alphaRef ? -1 : 1);

However, in trying these techniques, I've noticed that they deviate from results that HW Alpha test returned (as evidenced by extra, or less pixels being affected).

The technique I'm currently using involves doing the following:

```
float alphaVal = readFromTexture(uv).a;
float alphaRef = 0.5;

float enableLessTest = 0.0; // 1.0 (off/on)
float enableGreaterTest = 1.0; 
float enableEqualTest = 0.0;

// Greater test
clip((alphaRef - alphaVal) * enableGreaterTest);
// Less test
clip((alphaVal - alphaRef) * enableLessTest);<br />
// Equal test
float equality = (alphaVal == alphaRef) ? -1 : 1
clip(equiality * enableEqualTest);
```

Now the above exhibits the issues described where pixels on the edge of the alpha tested area are discarded by the HW, but included by the SW version.

I'm pretty sure it is a problem related to the precision that this calculation is being performed in, I assume the alpha test in HW uses Integer comparisions instead of float, however, I am trying to keep this shader ps_2 compliant.

I tried performing the following operation on alphaVal:
alphaVal = trunc(alphaVal * 255)/255;
with no luck.

I also tried flooring/truncing the various calculations inside the clip functions, however I can't seem to get exactly the right pixels returned, there are always either more or less pixels returned.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm sure someone must have done this before?

I'm beginning to wonder if this might also be hardware specific too. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Josh